# Google GAX / gRPC in Node.js Does Not Work With HTTP/S Proxy

Tags: proxy, dialogflow-es, grpc, grpc-node

I am trying to get Dialogflow SDK samples from Google's Dialogflow v2 Node.js SDK to work.  I am using node.js `v8.10.0`, with dialogflow node.js SDK version `0.5.0`.  I am encountering this issue when trying to run the "Detect Intent" sample, **from behind a corporate http/s proxy**:

```
Auth error:Error: write EPROTO 140163148314432:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827
```

I came across this post here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a which seemed very java-oriented, but it suggested that the environment variable `GRPC_PROXY_EXP` be set in order to get the gRPC calls to work behind a proxy.  I set the environment variable in the shell from which I was running node with `export GRPC_PROXY_EXP="$https_proxy"` and attempted to run the sample again, with the same issue. Note that my `$http_proxy`, `$https_proxy` variables are the same.

The same sample works from the same machine, when connected to a wifi network without the proxy; and a `tcpdump` packet analysis indicates that there are two TCP connections (distinct ports) in-use: one which works (and is opened first), and one which doesn't, and encounters the error with the proxy.  The second connection immediately begins the `CLIENT_HELLO` TLS message, when it needs to first authenticate and send the HTTPS proxy the `CONNECT` message (as the first TCP connection does).

Am I missing something, or is this an issue with the dialogflow (google-gax / grpc) node library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back-and-forth on a couple of Google node project issue discussion boards, the problem turned out to be that - when HTTPS over HTTP tunneling is used - the `gtoken` API's direct use of the `axios` npm package was only prepared to use HTTPS (consistent with the protocol in the URL).

To make a long story short; `Dialogflow 0.8.2` contains the fix for this issue in that its transitive dependencies include a version of the `gtoken` package that uses `gaxios` instead of `axios`.  `gaxios` is a package used elsewhere in the `google-gax` library to make HTTP/S connections (which is proxy aware, and handles the HTTPS over HTTP use-case).

Comment: How to include the right version of dialog flow into the nodejs dependencies? Here's my dependencies (and I am facing the issue): "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",  "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"

Comment: "dialogflow": "0.8.2"

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using dialogflow now, I'm using dialogflow-fullfillment